# preg_match always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below I control if the id in the database is a number. My problem is: the regular expression where I test the id always gives the nummber 0 back never 1 - even when the id is a number.

Can you help me to solve this?

This is the code with the problem:

```
$muster = "|^[0-9]+$|";
if(preg_match($muster, $_POST["Anzahl"]) == 0 || preg_match($muster, $_POST["id"]) == 0  || $_POST["Anzahl"] < 1) {
    die("<a href='javascript:history.back()'>Eingabe überprüfen</a>");
}
```

Comment: Those `|` should be forward slashes `/`. Pipes are an `or` operator when used inside parenthesis `()`. You could try using a regex tester like https://regex101.com/ . It gives great details.

Comment: the problem is only the id check: preg_match($muster, $_POST["id"]) == 0
This does not work. The other things work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PHPValidate filters

Its easier and more convenient:

```
<?php
  $str = "100";

  if (filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
      echo("Variable is an integer");
  } else {
      echo("Variable is not an integer");
  }
?>
```

If `filter_var(($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))` is successful it will return 100 as integer, otherwise false

Btw there are many usefull filter: http://php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: `filter_input` would be more appropriate for `$_POST`.